# Main activity layoutInflater, activity don't start

Tags: android, layout, program-entry-point, layout-inflater

When i hit the plbutton1 i don't take result.
When i hit the plbutton2 the activity R.layout.paraggeleia open corect.
Can anyone help me?
Where i make wrong? 
 Here is my code!!!!

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Bundle args = getArguments();
        switch (args.getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)){

        case 1: 
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.paraggeleia, container, false);
            Button bTutorial = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.plbutton2);
            bTutorial.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                 public void onClick(View v){
                  getActivity().startActivity(new Intent (getActivity(), parageleiaproionta.class));

                  Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Loaging Προιόντα", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                 }
             });
     return v;

        case 2:
            View m =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.paraggeleia, container, false);

             Button b1Tutorial = (Button) m.findViewById(R.id.plbutton1);
            b1Tutorial.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                  public void onClick(View m){
                   getActivity().startActivity(new Intent (getActivity(), sxetika.class));

                   Toast.makeText(m.getContext(), "Loaging Προιόντα", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                  }
              });
      return m;

    }

        return getView();

}


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe beacause You have switch and only second statement will be handled.

Comment: What you mean? please explane.

Comment: You have switch "switch (args.getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER))", and ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = 2, and only code from case 2: is being executed, therefore only clicking on second button get result

Comment: public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "2";  i make it but second button does not start activity again.